Assuming I invest 100 dollars as my capital, is it possible that the market could go badly below my investment?
Learning about risk in shares. want to be sure that investing in shares is equivalent to saving money in the bank with the only difference that you'll get profit for investing in stock.

I think the other answers overcomplicate things.
If you invest £100 in a bank account, you are guaranteed to be able to get your £100 back when you want to withdraw it. If the bank account pays interest, say at 3% pa and you leave the money in there for a year, you will be able to withdraw £103. The absolute worst that can happen is that the bank goes bankrupt, you get back your £100 under government guarantees, and it's not worth quite as much as it was when you invested it at the start of the year due to inflation.
If you invest £100 in buying stocks, there are no guarantees of anything. The stocks you buy could lose all their value and you cannot get a penny back when you want to withdraw your money. On the flip side they could rise substantially in value and you might be able to sell them for £200 a year later, effectively doubling your investment. You can't lose more than the original £100, you can't end up owing money - but other than that, the outcome could be anything.
In summary:

Low risk, low but guaranteed reward, no risk of losing investment: bank account
High risk, potentially high but not guaranteed reward, potential of losing entire investment: stocks


One addendum. In more exotic investments like short trading, you can lose more than your investment amount. The takeaway: Only invest in things you understand the risks.

Below your investment, yes, meaning your $100 stock could be worth, say, $75 after a period of time. If you buy stock, the most you can lose is what you have invested. If the company goes bankrupt and the stock is worthless, you lose your investment, but nothing more.

want to be sure that investing in shares is equivalent to saving money in the bank with the only difference that you'll get profit for investing in stock.

Not at all - there is a real possibilty of losing money, especially in the short term.  With a bank account, you earn a relatively small but guaranteed amount of interest. With stocks, you have the potential of losing money but also the potential of making a lot more money.
In general, with investing there is always a tradeoff of risk and reward. The more you're willing to risk, the more potential reward you have, but also the more potential for losses.
Mutual funds (and ETFs) are safer than individual stocks because it's very very unlikely that every stock in a fund will become worthless. However, the potential gains of a fund are less as well. You are more likely to see a stock gain in value 5 times over (a "5 bagger") than you are a fund.
If you're brand new to investing, the key advice is to never invest more in individual stocks than you are willing to lose completely. You can also put "stop losses" in place to sell your stocks if they lose more than a specific amount (say 20%) so you don't risk losing everything.

I am not an investor in stocks, so I could be wrong, but my understanding is that a "stop loss" order still doesn't guarantee anything. All it means is that your broker will attempt to sell your stocks if the price falls below a certain level, but if there are no buyers and the stock becomes worthless you've still lost everything.

@Vicky that's true - an extremely precipitous drop would force a sale well below the stop loss. But in general it is a cheap an effective way to limit losses.

Investing in equities is NOT equivalent to putting money into a bank account. A bank account guarantees that your deposit will not lose value (except to inflation); investments do not make that promise. In exchange for that safety, you accept a lower rate of return than you might be able to get by investing; essentially you are paying the bank to assume the risk.
A basic "I don't know details about individual companies and I don't want to know" investment in US stock market index funds -- betting on the market as a whole -- historically has averaged somewhere around 8% return, much better than you'd get from a bank. But in exchange you have to be willing to tolerate the fact that the value varies continuously, and can go in both directions.
You also have to neither become overconfident when it happens to soar for a while nor overly panicked when it happens to go in the other direction. We saw both unreasonable highs during the start of the pandemic period, and unreasonable lows a few years later. Those of us who just waited out the dip did fine; the market is coming back to right about that 8% per annum long-term growth average. Those who bought when the market was high or sold when the market was low didn't do as well. If you don't have the confidence to set AND STAY WITH a specific well-understood and verified strategy, the market may not be where you want most of your money.
Risk is indeed tied to return. People decide what the value of a stock is by balancing those. I'm not willing to do that kind of research, so I stick with a basic mix of index funds; I won't beat the market, but I'm unlikely to fall much short of it either.

I started working in 2007, and at the end of the year, had a small amount of money saved (I didn't have much expenses, was still living with my parents, etc). My mom's financial advisor signed me up for an equity ETF. He made 1% off my insvestment as comission, and my fund lost half its value when the markets crashed! I don't know when, or even if, I finally broke even, but it was over 8 years at least. If I had taken my money out at the bottom of the market, I would have lost half the money I had put in. That's the sort of losses you're looking at with diversified investments like ETFs. On the other hand, for a non-diversified high risk investment like a penny stock, you risk losing your money entirely. My mom still has stocks which have been delisted and even though they aren't worth 0 (the companies still exist), figuring how to sell them has been taking years with no end in sight. So it's practically worth 0. You could do worse though. Leveraged instruments can actually cost you more than the amount you paid to buy them! Don't touch them unless you know what you're doing (and it'd still make sense to hedge in some way)

If a leveraged position involves a margin loan, you could lose more than your investment. However, this is not the case with buying options or leveraged ETFs
